# Do I have to purchase support to ask questions on how to access Blob storage?

Tags: ios, windows, blob

We currently about 100 gig of data in blob storage and after purchasing windows clients to access the data 
We have a request to access from IOS device 
How would one access Blob storage from an IOS device?

Comment: What does the title of your question have to do with the question you actually posted?

Comment: the title is I don't know ware to get help to use blob storage

Answer (score 0):

No purchases necessary. MSoft has iOS libraries to provide access to their services.

look here; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-ios-how-to-use-blob-storage

From that page, an example to download a blob;

```
  -(void)downloadBlobToString
  {
      NSError *accountCreationError;

      // Create a storage account object from a connection string.
      AZSCloudStorageAccount *account = [AZSCloudStorageAccount accountFromConnectionString:@"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=your_account_name_here;AccountKey=your_account_key_here" error:&accountCreationError];

      if(accountCreationError){
         NSLog(@"Error in creating account.");
      }

      // Create a blob service client object.
      AZSCloudBlobClient *blobClient = [account getBlobClient];

      // Create a local container object.
      AZSCloudBlobContainer *blobContainer = [blobClient containerReferenceFromName:@"containerpublic"];

      // Create a local blob object
      AZSCloudBlockBlob *blockBlob = [blobContainer blockBlobReferenceFromName:@"sampleblob"];

      // Download blob
      [blockBlob downloadToTextWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error, NSString *text) {
          if (error) {
              NSLog(@"Error in downloading blob");
          }
          else{
              NSLog(@"%@",text);
          }
      }];
  }
```

Comment: can I do this on an IPhone?

Comment: what do I do with  iOS libraries

Comment: can I get them from apple app store?

Comment: iOS libraries are pre-written code modules to perform specific tasks. If they are called "iOS" then they are for the iPhone and iPad. In this case the iOS libraries are from Microsoft and are free. You get them here (https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-ios). You use them to write apps for the iPhone and iPad. Or hire me to do it! ;)